# Last empty string not included when splitting string into array by delim

Tags: linux, bash, shell, split

I am writing a script that takes a parameter with '~' delimiter and after splitting the string I want to insert the values into the array. I have quite a few posts on this problem and I am almost there but there a case where it fails. Here are the details.

myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpIFS=$IFS
IFS="~"
array=($1)
IFS=$tmpIFS
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

Executions

```
$ ./myScript.sh "A~B"
$ 2
```

Which is what I want. But when I do

```
$ ./myScript.sh "A~"
$ 1
```

I was expecting to have a array of size 2 again and the last cell to be an empty string.

How can I achieve that?

What I am trying to achieve in general with this script is to perform an http request using curl by passing 10 query parameters in it. Instead of having 10 parameters to my script I was thinking to get the data as one parameter delimited by a character in a specified order.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you included more information about what you were ultimately trying to achieve, we could present you with some alternatives.

Comment: What's the difference between having 10 parameters to your script and having one parameter but splitting it yourself? You could just do `./myScript.sh A B` and access your arguments via `$1` and `$2`. If you did `./myScript.sh A ''`, or even just `./myScript.sh A`, then `$2` would be empty.

Comment: @TomFenech What you say seems reasonable and much much easier and clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `~` are handled like white spaces in your expression, so the behavior makes sense with shell expansion rules. You can use the following workaround:

```
array=($1"")
```

To understand why this works, consider it with spaces (unchanged `IFS`): Assume `$1` is `A B C`, then

```
array=($1)
```

expands to

```
array=(A B C )
```

which is an array of three elements. On the other hand,

```
array=($1"")
```

expands to

```
array=(A B C "")
```

which has four. If there is no space at the end of `$1`, this expands to

```
array=(A B C"")
```

which is the same as `(A B C)` again.

Answer (score 0):

use `./script "A~ "` then the last element is "empty".

Comment: In this case it won't be an empty string but a space character which is not what I want. Input parameter will come from other applications so having a space is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: then possibly trim when accessing the element afterwards. i think bash won't handle/get the last element if there is none like in `./script "A~"`.

Comment: In order to get the space character at the end I have to add this login in all the clients which doesn't seem right. If it is not possible then I will have to follow a totally different path. :(